# ORA-00920: invalid relational operator in insert into

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

Keep getting ORA-00920: invalid relational operator on line 17 (es2.EMNEKODE LIKE 'STAT360').

But i can't figure out why the database suddenly does not accept the LiKE operator..:

Any suggestions?

```
 INSERT INTO database.EMNE_I_STUDIEPROGRAM es
(
    STUDIEPROGRAMKODE,
    INSTITUSJONSNR,
    EMNEKODE,
    VERSJONSKODE,
    STATUS_RAPPORTERING,
    STATUS_PUBLISERES,
    STATUS_KREV_EMNEVALG
)
(
    SELECT es2.STUDIEPROGRAMKODE, 
           es2.INSTITUSJONSNR,
           'STAT340',
           '1',
           es2.STATUS_RAPPORTERING,
           es2.STATUS_PUBLISERES,
           es2.STATUS_KREV_EMNEVALG
    FROM database.EMNE_I_STUDIEPROGRAM es2
    WHERE es2.EMNEKODE LIKE 'STAT360'
      and es2.VERSJONSKODE LIKE '1'
      and es2.STUDIEPROGRAMKODE NOT IN (
            SELECT es3.STUDIEPROGRAMKODE
            FROM
                database.EMNE_I_STUDIEPROGRAM es3
            WHERE
                es3.EMNEKODE LIKE 'STAT340'
                and es3.VERSJONSKODE LIKE '1'
          )
);
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `EMNEKODE`? Like only makes sence with placeholder

Comment: First Execute your select query and check Whether it is working or not?? after that check the data type of EMNEKODE column  in EMNE_I_STUDIEPROGRAM table is varchar2 or not.

Comment: I don't get an error running your code. If you're running multiple statements in a script, are you sure it's coming from this one?

Comment: EMNEKODE is VARCHAR(2).
Also tried with = operator hitting the same error.
The select query alone hit the same error..

Comment: Does it still error if you copy the code from the question and run that? (Possibly there's a dodgy character in your real code that has been converted to something sane in the question). Can you copy and paste an SQL\*Plus session showing the code being executed and the error, exactly as you see it? Preferably still as text not an image. Which client are you running it in now, and which version of that and the database are you using?

Comment: Tnx, that solved it :D

Answer (score 0):

Does it still error if you copy the code from the question and run that? (Possibly there's a dodgy character in your real code that has been converted to something sane in the question).  Alex Poole 3 hours ago